# How to convert RenderBox global position coordinates for Tween<Offset>?

Tags: animation, flutter, offset, tween

I'm attempting to create my own `Hero` style transition using a `SlideTransition` with the position `Offset` starting at where the user taps the item on the previous screen.

This is what I'm currently using for receiving the coordinate value of where the user is tapping the screen (I only need the `dy` value):

```
GestureDetector(
    child: //stuff
    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) async {
        RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
        double position = box.localToGlobal(details.globalPosition).dy;
            await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return SecondPage(startPosition: position);
        }));
    },
)
```

I then pass this onto the `SecondPage` and use it as the starting position of the `Animation<Offset>` in my `initState`:

```
@override
void initState() {
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    offset = new Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(0.0, widget.startPosition), end: Offset.zero).animate(curve);
    controller.forward();
    super.initState();
}
```

The issue I'm having is finding a way to properly convert the `dy` value to one which matches what the `Tween<Offset>` uses as the `dy` value comes in with a value of say `250-300` for half way down the screen but the same for the `Offset(0.0, widget.startPosition)` would be around `2.0` for it to match the same position. I've tried various maths to match these (such as dividing the `dy` by the screens height) but I haven't found anything which matches it exactly.

If anyone knows the correct method/exact maths I have to perform on matching these values I'll love you forever.

Edit: Self contained example of what I'm trying to achieve which you can play around with. This is currently with me using `double position = (box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition).dy) / box.size.height * 3;` as this is around the closest match I've found.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo.shade200,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 35),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {},
            )),
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 11),
                  child:
                      Column(children: <Widget>[Stack(children: getCards())]))),
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0))),
              child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink.shade300)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.sentiment_satisfied),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Text('Tab1',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black38))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink.shade300)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Text('Tab2',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black38))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink.shade300)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Text('Tab3',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black38))
                      ],
                    )
                  ])))
        ]));
  }

  List<Widget> getCards() {
    List<Widget> widgets = new List<Widget>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      widgets.add(GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: (i * 175).toDouble()),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
          height: 300.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: getColor(i),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0)),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                      child: Text('Text ' + (i + 1).toString(),
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 26.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) async {
          RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject();
          double position = (box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition).dy) / box.size.height * 3;
          await Navigator.push(context, CustomPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return SecondPage(index: i, startPosition: position);
          }));
        },
      ));
    }
    return widgets.reversed.toList();
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final double startPosition;

  SecondPage({this.index, this.startPosition});

  @override
  State createState() => SecondPageState();
}

class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation curve;
  Animation<Offset> offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    offset = new Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(0.0, widget.startPosition), end: Offset.zero)
        .animate(curve);
    controller.forward();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
        body: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
              SlideTransition(
                  position: offset,
                  child: Container(
                      height: 200.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: getColor(widget.index),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0))),
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28.0),
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                                    },
                                  )),
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon:
                                        Icon(Icons.launch, color: Colors.white),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      print("launch website");
                                    },
                                  )),
                                  Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width /
                                              5),
                                      child: Material(
                                            color: Colors.transparent,
                                            child: Text('Text ' + (widget.index + 1).toString(),
                                              maxLines: 2,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontSize: 26.0,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold)))))
                            ],
                          ))))
            ])));
  }
}

class CustomPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  CustomPageRoute({WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings})
      : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
      Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
    return child;
  }
}

Color getColor(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return Colors.pink.shade300;
    case 1:
      return Colors.purple.shade300;
    case 2:
      return Colors.deepPurple.shade400;
    case 3:
      return Colors.deepPurple.shade900;
    case 4:
      return Colors.indigo.shade900;
    default:
      return Colors.red;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it depends a little on what you're doing with the build function for the SecondPage. Could you include the rest of your code - it'd be best if it were a self-contained example we could try running.

Comment: Not really. I'm just using a `SlideTransition` on the SecondPage to slide a Container from where it was clicked on the previous page and slide up to the top of the SecondPage. The issue is that the `SlideTransition` uses an `Offset` to "create a fractional translation" to know where to begin and end the sliding animation but I can't find of a way to convert the `dy` value from the `RenderBox`'s global `dy` to one the `Tween<Offset>` uses. I will provide a self contained example though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding a renderBox is not useful in this case, because all of the cards are places in a stack the context.findRenderObject finds the top most stack. That stack covers the entire screen so when you transform from global to local position you get the same position.

You can calculate the correct offset for you second screen like this:

```
  var scrollOffset = controller.position.pixels;
  double position =  ((i * 175).toDouble() + 100 - scrollOffset) / 200;
```

1. (i * 175) : Offset of every card from the top.
2. 100 : Height difference between height of cards in the first screen
   and second screen (300 in first and 200 in second). We add this to
   compansate for the difference so the cards position will be the
   same.
3. 200 : Height of the card in the second screen. We divide by this
   because

> The translation is expressed as an Offset scaled to the child's size

Finally you will need to give a scrollController to your SingleChildScrollView to get the scroll offset. Without the scroll offset you can't calculate the correct position if the cards are scrolled (i.e Card 4 or Card 5)

Here is how your HomePageState should look like.

```
class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo.shade200,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 35),
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
              foregroundColor: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {},
            )),
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: controller,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 11),
                  child:
                      Column(children: <Widget>[Stack(children: getCards())]))),
          Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0))),
              child: Center(
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink.shade300)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.sentiment_satisfied),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Text('Tab1',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black38))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink.shade300)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.trending_up),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Text('Tab2',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black38))
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                            child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                          child: Container(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 40.0,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 2.0, color: Colors.pink.shade300)),
                            child: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                          ),
                        )),
                        Text('Tab3',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black38))
                      ],
                    )
                  ])))
        ]));
  }

  List<Widget> getCards() {
    List<Widget> widgets = new List<Widget>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      widgets.add(GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: (i * 175).toDouble()),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(60.0),
          height: 300.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: getColor(i),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(100.0)),
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                      child: Text('Text ' + (i + 1).toString(),
                          maxLines: 2,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 26.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) async {
          var scrollOffset = controller.position.pixels;
          double position =  ((i * 175).toDouble() + 100 - scrollOffset) / 200;

          await Navigator.push(context, CustomPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return SecondPage(index: i, startPosition: position);
          }));
        },
      ));
    }
    return widgets.reversed.toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: I totally couldn't have figured this out myself you are a life saver. Awesome stuff!